# PostgreSQL same trigger function to UPDATE on INSERT into different tables (using the same schema)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have 100s of tables having the same schema and I have a trigger function to UPDATE some column whenever data is INSERTed into that table.

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE symbol_daily_ohlc (
 cdate date,
 open numeric(8,2),
 high numeric(8,2),
 low numeric(8,2),
 close numeric(8,2),
 sma8 numeric(8,2)
);
```

Trigger function:

```
create or replace function update_sma8() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE symbol_daily_ohlc d SET sma8 = s.simple_mov_avg 
FROM
(
 SELECT  sec.cdate,AVG(sec.close)  
 OVER(ORDER BY sec.cdate ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 
 simple_mov_avg FROM symbol_daily_ohlc sec
)s where s.cdate = NEW.cdate  --The newly inserted cdate
 AND d.cdate = s.cdate;   
RETURN NULL;
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

Trigger setup on table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_update_sma
AFTER INSERT ON symbol_daily_ohlc
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_sma8();
```

This is working well for the given table i.e symbol_daily_ohlc. I would like to use the same trigger function i.e update_sma8() to be used with any table having the same schema (I don't want to rewrite the same function for different tables).

I tried replacing the table name (i.e symbol_daily_ohlc) with TG_TABLE_NAME, but that didn't work - thrown errors. So how to do that?

Reference: [SQL trigger function to UPDATE daily moving average upon INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131201/sql-trigger-function-to-update-daily-moving-average-upon-insert)

Comment: You shouldn't have tables with the same schema.  If you are thinking of such a thing, you probably have an issue with your data model.  All that data should go into a single table with a column that defines whatever other attribute you want the data to have.

Comment: The database is to store historical data of stock market i.e of different symbols (stocks). I think this is better approach to study the particular stock.

Comment: And yet, having a column called "stock_symbol" would have meant this issue wouldn't have been. You can still have a million "tables" if you want.. `CREATE VIEW msft_history AS SELECT * FROM all_stock_history WHERE stock_symbol = 'MSFT';CREATE VIEW goog_history AS SELECT * FROM all_stock_history WHERE stock_symbol = 'GOOG'`

Comment: Instead of an `UPDATE` assign the values you want to the respective columns of the `new` pseudo record. Then you won't have a table name in the trigger body and can use it for every table that has the columns you address (with compatible types of course).

Comment: @stickybit, could you please tell me how to do that. Being a newbie, I couldn't get that clearly.

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard & GordonLinoff for your suggestions. I would evaluate your suggestions for sure.

Comment: @selvask: Sorry, forget my comment. I though the table you select from was another one. But now I realize it's the same the trigger is on.

Comment: @selvask . . . No.  Separate tables are not a better approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I accepted your suggestion and I have changed my database accordingly. Thanks to  you and Caius Jard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a same procedure that executes and returns a Trigger for all the tables, but you can't have a same Trigger for all your tables.

Here's a block that dynamically creates a Trigger with table name suffix ( using `EXECUTE format`)

```
DO $$
declare
tabs RECORD;
BEGIN
for tabs IN
(select table_name,table_schema
   from information_schema.tables where table_name 
   like 'symbol_daily_ohlc%' 
  -- and table_schema like '%'
) LOOP
EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER check_update_%I
    AFTER INSERT ON %I.%I
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_sma8()',tabs.table_name,
 tabs.table_schema
,tabs.table_name);
END LOOP;
END $$;
```

And here's your Trigger, which takes the table name dynamically from `TG_TABLE_NAME`

```
create or replace function update_sma8() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
 BEGIN

EXECUTE format ('UPDATE %I d SET sma8 = s.simple_mov_avg 
FROM
(
 SELECT  sec.cdate,AVG(sec.close)  
   OVER(ORDER BY sec.cdate ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 
    simple_mov_avg FROM %I sec
)s where s.cdate = %L  --The newly inserted cdate
     AND d.cdate = s.cdate',TG_TABLE_NAME,TG_TABLE_NAME,NEW.cdate);   
RETURN NULL;

END $$ language plpgsql;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cb2f6e8e21a19ba957427185c12138e5)

As others have suggested, it's not a good idea to have multiple tables with the same structure. You should consider combining them into one table.

Comment: That's so nice of you to answer. Thank you. I would evaluate others suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably have to use SQL to generate SQL, then run the generated SQL. Something like:

```
select CONCAT('create or replace function update_sma8() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
  BEGIN
  UPDATE ', table_name, '  d SET sma8 = s.simple_mov_avg 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT  sec.cdate,AVG(sec.close)  
   OVER(ORDER BY sec.cdate ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 
   simple_mov_avg FROM ', table_name, '
  )s where s.cdate = NEW.cdate  --The newly inserted cdate
  AND d.cdate = s.cdate;   
  RETURN NULL;
  END $$ language plpgsql;
') from information_schema.tables
```

But really you should consider Gordon's advice (and my followup) and put all your data back in one table:

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO all_hist SELECT ''', table_name, ''', t.* FROM ', table_name) FROM information_schema.tables
```

This will generate a bunch of sqls that put all the table data into all_hist, a table that should have an identical schema to the other thousands, except for an additional column "symbol" or whatever..

You can use a similar trick to create yourself a bunch of views to recreate the thousands-table approach if you really want..

Comment: Thank you for answering. I would evaluate your suggestion.